# How to add C/C++ functions to Objective-C code (iphone related)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, ios4

I added .h/.cpp files with C functions to my Xcode project. How would I call a C function in an objective-C function?

When I included the C file (#import "example.h") in the app delegate header file it exploded with errors (could be that it treated the cpp file as objective-c) even though it compiles fine without being included/imported.

Thanks

Edit: Renaming all the files from m to mm fixed the issue. However I am getting a linker error when building (ld: duplicate symbol)... Better research this first. Thanks again all.

Comment: This usually "just works".  It would be helpful if you'd share the error messages that it "exploded" with.

Comment: You might want to try an #include instead of an #import.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use C++ with your Objective-C module, change the file extension from `.m` to `.mm`.

Answer (score 7):

- To use plain C in Objective-C just
  include the header/source file as
  usual and call the functions. The C
  files can use the standard extension
  `.h` and `.c`. A lot of
  libraries are already used this way
  such as libxml and sqlite.
- To write C code that can use
  Objective-C (access
  FoundationFramework) it will need to
  be placed in a `.m` file. A `.m` file
  can contain all C functions just like
  the main.m generated with new
  projects.
- To call C++ code the C++ can be in a
  `.cpp` (or other valid extension) but
  your Objective-C file needs the
  extension `.mm` to call it, and once
  again simply include the header file.
  And to use Objective-C inside of a
  C++ class it will need the `.mm`
  extension.

Answer (score 2):

C functions should be callable without doing anything special. Objective-C is a superset of C.

If the headers include C++ stuff, then you need to compile your files as Objective-C++ instead of Objective-C.  To do this, just change the file extensions from `.m` to `.mm`.