# symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 when importing cpp file from iOS Sample Project

Tags: c++, ios, core-audio

All,

I have downloaded a Sample Project for Audio conversion:
https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html

I had to take away all CAXException codes and CADebugPrintf codes. But then when I was trying to call the ExtAudioFileConvert.cpp's DoConvertFile function, it shows

"_DoConvertFile", referenced from:
....
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed this post to remove  "Preprocessor Macros" Setting

[iOS,CoreAudio: a strange 'CADebugPrintf.h: no such file or directory ... ' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916690/ios-coreaudio-a-strange-cadebugprintf-h-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

and followed this post to add a .mm file as C++ wrapper to call DoConvertFile

[How to add C/C++ functions to Objective-C code (iphone related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551501/how-to-add-c-c-functions-to-objective-c-code-iphone-related)

Problem fixed!